# Dynamically Embed Html Attribute in C# ASP.NET View

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to dynamically set an attribute(data-status) for a div if a condition is met.

I am currently using the @Html.Raw helper however it's not making its way in to the element.

I have also attempted to use Response.Write() however it just writes everything to the top of the page.

Is there a best way to actually embed this in to the code or maybe create/set a new attribute?

```
@foreach (var r in Model)
    {
        <div class="marker"
             data-date="@r.date_finished"
             data-name="@r.name"

             @if (r.complete == "CP")
                 {
                     @Html.Raw("data-status='complete'");
                 }
         >
         </div>
     }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<div class="marker"
     data-date="@r.date_finished"
     data-name="@r.name"
     @{if (r.complete == "CP") { <text>data-status='complete'</text> }}>
```

Notice the usage of `<text>` tag. This is a special tag which Razor uses to output content as is.

Comment: Perfect! This worked very well. Also, a small edit but it should be data-status='complete'. I was doing this wrong in the example I provided just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

When I run into this scenario I use a tertiary expression:

```
<div @(r.complete == "CP" ? "data-status='complete'" : "") >
```

If your logic is more complex you could also use a static helper method.

```
<div @r.RenderComplete() >

public static class  RExtension{
    public static string RenderComplete( this R r){
        // logic here
    }
}
```